# How to plot moving average for many dataFrames in R

Tags: r

I have a some data frames, and for example, 8th dframe is `dfQ[[8]]` :

```
c(16, 14, 15, 14, 14, 12, 13, 14, 13, 12, 13, 12, 12, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 16, 13, 12, 13, 12, 13, 12, 13, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 17, 17, 17, 18, 11, 12, 14, 13, 
13, 12, 11, 11, 11, 9, 9, 9, 11, 12, 12, 9, 13, 14, 14, 16, 12, 
15, 14, 14, 14, 14, 11, 13, 13, 14, 13, 13, 12, 11, 11, 11, 9, 
11, 11, 10, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 11, 12, 9, 12, 11, 
11, 9, 12, 12, 12, 13, 9, 14, 9, 12, 13, 9, 12, 12, 13, 13, 9, 
13, 14, 14, 13, 12, 13, 12, 12, 12, 11, 12, 9, 11, 8, 9, 9, 8, 
8, 1)
```

Its length is 134. I use the `movavg` into the `library(pracma)` for filtering this data (this function allow me to choose number and type filter).

**How to plot filtered data the elements in chosen range (for example 8th  dfQ[[8]] I chose the 124:134 range) for  data frames?**

I tried to use this code, but it is not working:

```r
par(las = 1)
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(0, 50), ylim = c(0,20),xlab = 'Steps',
ylab = '',type = 'n')
lines(movavg(dfQ[[8]][(length(dfQ[[8]])-30):length(dfQ[[8]])],10, type ="s"),
type= "o",pch=16,lwd=0.4, lty=3, xlab = 'Steps', ylab = '',cex = 0.6,
col = "darkblue")
abline(h=c(10), lwd=2, lty=1, col="red")
mtext("MAX D A.U.", col = "black", adj=-0.05, padj=-0.1, cex=0.8)
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL,lty = 2, col = "gray", lwd = 1)
```

I get error:

```
Error in movavg(dfL_F[[assemble1[i]]][(length(dfL_F[[assemble1[i]]]) -  :
  Window length 'n' must be greater then length of time series.
```

Comment: Your code cannot work with the sample data you provided. It's really helpful when we don't have to parse through your code to adapt to the sample data you give us.

Comment: @r2evans

I edit my code

Comment: *"it is not working"* ... what is wrong? If there is an error or warning, please include the literal text (in a code block). I don't have `pracma` installed, but I have to wonder ... `dfQ[[8]][(length(dfQ[[8]])-30)]:length(dfQ[[8]])` seems wrong, the `:` seems more fitting between `30)` and `length`, but you have a `]` in there. I wonder if it should instead be `dfQ[[8]][(length(dfQ[[8]])-30):length(dfQ[[8]])]`.

Comment: @r2evans

Sorry, You are right, I forget ]... But I can't plot moving average

Comment: Okay, well ... I still don't have `pracma` installed, I hope somebody who's more familiar with it will come and help. If the `]` was in the wrong place, you should really update the code as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for correcting my code! This problem relies on the correct choice of methods for my specific data:

```r
par(las = 1)
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(0, 50), ylim = c(0,0.05),xlab = 'Steps',
ylab = '',type = 'n')
lines(movavg(dfQ[[8]][(length(dfQ[[8]])-30):length(dfQ[[8]])],10,type = "r"),type= "o",pch=16,lwd=0.4, lty=3, xlab = 'Число шагов', ylab = '',cex = 0.6,
col = "darkblue")
abline(h=c(0.004500), lwd=2, lty=1, col="red")
mtext("MAX D A.U.", col = "black", adj=-0.05, padj=-0.1, cex=0.8)
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL,lty = 2, col = "gray", lwd = 1
```